# Continue scrolling UITableView when superView is at the top

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `MainViewController` with a `bottomSheet` as a childViewController on top of it.

The `bottomSheet` at first is presented on 1/4 of the `MainViewController`, with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` attached to it and a `UITableView` as a subView of the `bottomSheet` pinned to the 4 edges of the view.

I can pan the bottomSheet and move it to the top of the screen. However, when it reaches the top, I need to release my finger and pan again so the `UITableView` receives the touch.

I need a way so when the view is at the top of the screen, it starts scrolling the tableView.

What I have tried is `UIPanGestureRecognizer`'s `changed` state and `setContentOffset` of the `UITableView`, this gave me a final result, but with some issues, as it loses the system default animations

Is there a way to continue scrolling the tableView without releasing my finger?

Comment: tableview is in mainVC or as subview in sheet ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan subview in sheet

Comment: isn't tableView goes up with the sheet or it's size is larger than screen size , you may add a gif of your current issue

Comment: The tableView goes up with the sheet, but when the sheet reaches the top of the screen, the tableView will not continue scrolling unless I released my finger and scrolled it. What I want is when the sheet reaches the top, the tableView continue scrolling.

Comment: Add the pan to the tableview and stretch as in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Give the tableView it's complete height before even panning , where **tableViewHeightCon** is the height constraint of the tableView dragged as IBOutlet

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

      self.tableViewHeightCon.constant = numberOFCells*cellHeight;

    }
```

and when you detect the view is at most top change the top constraint of the table view like this

```
    func scrollTableAutomatic
   {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {

        self.tableViewTopCon.constant -= self.tableView.frame.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height


    }

   }
```